Understanding the Electron-Positron Transformation in Dirac's 2-Spinor Notation - Penrose
Penrose in his book, the road to reality, chapter 25, it says:

non-standard way, by re-examining the Dirac equation in terms of the
‘2-spinor notation’, briefly introduced in §22.8. As remarked in §24.8
above, a ‘Pauli spinor’ description for a particle of spin ½ is a
2-component quantity ψ_A (The components are ψ_0 and ψ_1.) When
considering relativity, according to §22.8, we also need quantities
with primed indices A’, B’, C’, . . . , the primed indices resulting
from complex conjugation applied to unprimed indices. It turns out^2
that the Dirac spinor ψ, as described above, with its 4 complex
components, can be represented, as a pair of 2-spinors^3 α_A and β_A’,
one with an unprimed index and one with a primed index:
ψ = (α_A, β_A’).
The Dirac equation can then be written as an equation coupling these
two 2-spinors, each acting as a kind of ‘source’ for the other, with a
‘coupling constant’ 2^(-1/2)M describing the strength of the
‘interaction’ between the two:
∇_(B’ A) α_A = 2^(-1/2) M β_(B’), ∇_(B A’) β_(B’) = 2^(-1/2) M α_(A’).
The operators ∇^A_B and ∇^B'_A are just 2-spinor translations of the
ordinary gradient operator ∇. Do not worry about all those indices,
the 2^(-1/2)s, and the exact form of these equations. I present them
here just to indicate how the Dirac equation can be brought into the
general framework of the 2-spinor calculus, and that, when this is
done, some new insights as to the nature of Dirac’s equation are
revealed.^4
From the form of these equations, we see that the Dirac electron can
be thought of as being composed of two ingredients α_A and β_B'. It is
possible to obtain a kind of physical interpretation of these
ingredients. We form a picture in which there are two ‘particles’, one
described by α_A and the other by β_A', each of which is
massless,^25.1 and where each one is continually converting itself
into the other one. Let us call these the ‘zig’ particle and the ‘zag’
particle, where α_A describes the zig and β_A' describes the zag.
Being massless, each of these should be travelling with the speed of
light, but we can think of them, rather, as ‘jiggling’ backwards and
forwards where the forward motion of the zig is continually being
converted to the backward motion of the zag and vice versa. In fact,
this is a realization of the phenomenon referred to as
‘zitterbewegung’, according to which, the electron’s instantaneous
motion is always measured to be the speed of light, owing to the
electron’s jiggling motion, even though the overall averaged motion of
the electron is less than light speed.^5 Each ingredient has a spin
about its direction of motion, of magnitude ½ ħ, where the spin is ....

The question I have is this: Considering the Dirac spinor, which is a 4-component spinor, we can think of it as two bispinors. The first two components represent the electron ( one components represents the probability of spin up and the other the probability of spin down), while the last two components represent the positron.
Does the transformation ∇_(B’ A) α_A = 2^(-1/2) M β_(B’), which converts the first bispinor into the second bispinor, imply that the electron is converted into the positron? Thats what I'm not getting.
